# Agrupamento no foreach e na view não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Criei e setei uma variável para controlar o seguinte. A minha LINQ me retorna hoje 5 mil linhas. Essa variável, ela está lá para evitar que se repita a mesma coisa, tipo. Digamos que a linq me retorne 400 motivo de ID=1. Logo essa variável, eu a seto para que apenas o Motivo 1 só apareça na tela uma vez. Bem, isso funcionou. Qual o problema então? Para um único motivo, eu tenho 5 Unidade_Negocio, por exemplo. Essa UN pode se repetir várias vezes, conforme dito para o motivo. Fiz semelhante ao Motivo e não funcionou.

1) O IF que eu fiz, é printado na página.
2) Mesmo que eu tenha mais de uma UN para cada Motivo, só é mostrado uma UN e nada mais e assim para os demais níveis abaixo da UN.
3) Acho que o problema está na Controller. Abaixo a minha controller(ActionResul) e a minha View(Apenas a parte que monta a TreeView.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Acao()
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            var monta_arvore = db.Ruptura.Where(m => m.IDMotivo != 6)  
                               .Select(rup=>

                               new MontaArvoreAcao{
                                   IDRuptura = rup.IDRuptura,
                                   DataRuptura = rup.DataRuptura,
                                   IDMotivo = rup.IDMotivo,
                                   Motivo = rup.Motivo.Motivo1,
                                   IDOrigem = rup.IDOrigem,
                                   CodigoPDV = rup.CodigoPDV,
                                   UF  = rup.PDV.UF,
                                   Cidade = rup.PDV.Cidade,
                                   CnpjDescricao= rup.PDV.Cnpj + " - " + rup.PDV.Descricao,
                                   Codigo_Apresentacao = rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
                                   Unidade_Negocio = rup.Apresentacao.Unidade_Negocio,
                                   Franquia = rup.Apresentacao.Franquia,
                                   Familia  = rup.Apresentacao.Familia,
                                   Descricao = rup.Apresentacao.Descricao
                               }).ToList().Take(50).OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo);

            return View(monta_arvore.ToList());
        }
```

A minha View:

```
@{
                var _motivo = "";
                var _un = "";
                var _familia = "";
            <ul>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (_motivo != @item.Motivo)
                    { 
                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                        @item.Motivo
                        <ul>
                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                @item.Unidade_Negocio
                                <ul>
                                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                        @item.Familia
                                        <ul>
                                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                                @item.Descricao
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                } 
                    _motivo = @item.Motivo;
                    _un = @item.Unidade_Negocio;
                    _familia = @item.Familia;
                }
            </ul>
           }
```

Pessoal, coloquei o group by na LINQ e não funcionou. Dá erro. Tentei fazer na view e tem esse o problema de que não reconhecer alguns campos. Alem do mais fiz uns IF's para controlar e acontece o seguinte. O primeiro IF que é sobre o Motivo, funciona, ou seja, não permite a repetição do Motivo. Já os demais não funcionam e são printados na tela. Veja como ficou minha View com esses IF's.

```
<div id='jqxWidget'>
    <div style='float: left; width:auto;'>
        <div id='jqxTree' style='visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 20px;'>

            @{
                var _motivo = "";
                var _un = "";
                var _familia = "";
            <ul>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (_motivo != item.Motivo)
                    { 
                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                        @item.Motivo
                        <ul>
                            if (_un != item.Unidade_Negocio)
                            { 
                            @foreach(var un in @item.Unidade_Negocio)
                            {
                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                @item.Unidade_Negocio
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach(var fam in @item.Familia)
                                    { 
                                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                        @item.Familia
                                        <ul>
                                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                                @item.Descricao
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                                        @item.CnpjDescricao
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    }
                                </ul>

                            </li>@*Unidade Negocio*@
                            }
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                } 
                    _motivo = @item.Motivo;
                    _un = @item.Unidade_Negocio;
                    _familia = @item.Familia;
                }
            </ul>
           }

        </div>
```

Deixa eu explicar.Na LINQ está tudo carregado, conforme modelo postado aqui.

Agora, quando eu carrego na View, é aí que acontece algumas coisas. Se eu coloco um GroupBy na LINQ, conforme exemplo postado, dá erro logo no primeiro registro, que no caso é o Motivo, mas poderia ser qualquer outro. Erro já postado aqui. A query me traz muita coisa repetida, tipo, Motivo, UN e etc... Aí declarei uma variável e dentro do foreach, ela será setada com o valor que ela estiver controlando, tipo: Vamos dizer Motivo. Ela está com valor vazio. Aí eu coloco um IF para saber se o valor da Variavel é diferente do Motivo. Caso seja(a primeira sempre é) e então carrego o Motivo. Se na próxima iteração, ela continuar igual, aí pula não repetindo o mesmo nome. Bem, como Motivo é o primeiro campo, isso está funcionando bem. Quando chego no UN, aí já não funciona. Porem, escrevendo esse post, acho que coloquei a var em lugar errado, ou seja, deveria estar no final do foreach da UN e não no foreach do Motivo, como está. Mas vou testar, mas de qualquer forma, não está funcionando os demais IF's. O primeiro funciona, mas os demais não. Isso é que está atrapalhando. Estou pesquisando na net, mas ainda não vi nada realmente que resolva meu problema com IF's aninhados dentro de uma View(CSHTML). Essa é minha dor de cabeça.

Comment: Você conhece o método [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb359331(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Sim, mas acho que não é isso. O problema não está no resultado da linq, mas sim na montagem da treeview e os checkbox's. Claro que tem a ver com a LINQ.

Comment: Então por que você não agrupa os resultados por Motivo e por Unidade de Negócio? Deixar isso pra View fica complicado e lento.

Answer (score 2):

Ja tentou o GrupBy com Distinct ao montar a List?

Algo parecido com:

```
public ActionResult Acao()
    {
        RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

        var monta_arvore = db.Ruptura.Where(m => m.IDMotivo != 6)  
                           .Select(rup=>

                           new MontaArvoreAcao{
                               IDRuptura = rup.IDRuptura,
                               DataRuptura = rup.DataRuptura,
                               IDMotivo = rup.IDMotivo,
                               Motivo = rup.Motivo.Motivo1,
                               IDOrigem = rup.IDOrigem,
                               CodigoPDV = rup.CodigoPDV,
                               UF  = rup.PDV.UF,
                               Cidade = rup.PDV.Cidade,
                               CnpjDescricao= rup.PDV.Cnpj + " - " + rup.PDV.Descricao,
                               Codigo_Apresentacao = rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
                               Unidade_Negocio = rup.Apresentacao.Unidade_Negocio,
                               Franquia = rup.Apresentacao.Franquia,
                               Familia  = rup.Apresentacao.Familia,
                               Descricao = rup.Apresentacao.Descricao
                           }).Distinct().ToList().Take(50).OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo).ToList().GroupBy(x => x.IDMotivo).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

        return View(monta_arvore.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Com GroupBy dá o seguinte arro:An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: 'object' não contém uma definição para 'Motivo'. Teria que colocar todos os campos da LINQ no  agrupamento